# Laravel hasMany relation count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There are many Categories(Category.php) on my index site, which has many Boards(Board.php).
A Board can have many Topics(Topic.php), and a Topic can have many Replies (Reply.php).

I want to fetch the number of replies of the current board, possibly with eager loading.

I have a way, but it executes too many queries. I create a post_count attribute, then I iterate over every topic and gather number of replies. Is there a way to select all replies from the current board?

```
public function getPostCountAttribute()
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($this->topics()->withCount('replies')->get() as $topic) {
        $count += $topic->replies_count;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a nice way. Even though, I'll leave this question open, if anyone finds a better way to do it.

I declared a `hasManyThrough` relationship, and the called the count():

Board.php:

```
public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Reply::class, Topic::class);
    }
```

And then called:

```
$board->replies->count()
```

30 queries executed (45 before).

Still, I would like to find an eager way to load the data, getting the query number down to 2 or 3 queries.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to your [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107028/2219158) you can do something like this.

```
 public function repliesCount() {
        return $this->replies()->selectRaw('board_id, count(*) as aggregate')
                        ->groupBy('board_id');
    }
```

and to use this use as below

```
$board->repliesCount()
```

*Please note that you have to change query according to you.*

Comment: I would give you two votes if possible. This answer works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try it 
**Change**

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($this->topics()->withCount('replies')->get() as $topic) {
    $count += $topic->replies_count;
}
```

**To**

```
$topic_ids = $this -> topics -> pluck('id');
$reply_count = Reply::whereIn('id',$topic_ids) -> count();
```

Comment: Shouldn't whereIn() have two arguments? Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereIn().. I changed to whereIn('topic_id', $topic_ids), no results.

Comment: Print and see if $topics_ids fetches you id. There seem nothing wrong in code.